# Is it safe to Install Both Redis and MySQL on the same system?

Tags: mysql, database

Mine is a question not on how to install either but on whether I can have both MySQL and Redis-Server on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I need both for different projects, any help forthcoming will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have any problems running both of them on the same system.

Comment: Thanks I have both now for 15 hours no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Security and encryption has been one of the issues with Redis. In their latest release they have probably taken care of it.
http://blogs.alachisoft.com/ncache/a-good-redis-alternative-open-source-distributed-cache/